# How to get GNU Parallel report every file processed?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I would like to keep track of GNU parallel in a simple log file and would like it to emit the name of each as it starts / ends (either or both are equally fine). It seems verbose is too verbose for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a profile that does the logging:

```
echo 'echo {} >> my.log;' > ~/.parallel/log
```

Then you can do this:

```
parallel -J log seq {} ::: 1 2 3
```

But since the profile uses {} you need to mention {} explicitly.

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
parallel -J log seq ::: 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking for `--joblog` then please explain how your needs differ.

`--joblog` is covered in 7.7 (p. 59) in GNU Parallel 2018 (paper copy: http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html or download it at: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014).